# CosmosDB Paging Return Value

Tags: rest, azure, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb, paging

I am trying to return paging results the request from CosmosDB. I saw this example from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.client.feedoptions.maxitemcount?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=azure-dotnet#overloads) but I am not sure what to do with the `response` variable.

```
// Fetch query results 10 at a time.
var queryable = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Book>(collectionLink, new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 10 });
while (queryable.HasResults)
{
    FeedResponse<Book> response = await queryable.ExecuteNext<Book>();
}
```

Am I suppose to return it directly? Or do I have to do something further with the `response` variable? I tried to return the response variable directly and it's not working. Here's my code:

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> RunQueryAsync(string queryString)
        {

            var feedOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 3 };
            IQueryable<T> filter = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(_collectionUri, queryString, feedOptions);
            IDocumentQuery<T> query = filter.AsDocumentQuery();
            var response = new FeedResponse<T>();
            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                response = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>();
            }
            return response;
        }
```

**Update**: 
After reading @Evandro Paula's answer, I followed the [URL](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/blob/d17c0ca5be739a359d105cf4112443f65ca2cb72/samples/code-samples/Queries/Program.cs#L554-L576) and changed my implementation to below. But it is still giving me 500 status code:

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> RunQueryAsync(string queryString)
        {
            var feedOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 1 };
            IQueryable<T> filter = _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(_collectionUri, queryString, feedOptions);
            IDocumentQuery<T> query = filter.AsDocumentQuery();
            List<T> results = new List<T>();
            while (query.HasMoreResults)
            {
                foreach (T t in await query.ExecuteNextAsync())
                {
                    results.Add(t);
                }
            }
            return results;
        }
```

And here's the exception message:

> Cross partition query is required but disabled. Please set
>   x-ms-documentdb-query-enablecrosspartition to true, specify
>   x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey, or revise your query to avoid this
>   exception., Windows/10.0.17134 documentdb-netcore-sdk/1.9.1

**Update 2**: 
I added the `EnableCrossPartitionQuery` to true and I am able to get the response from CosmosDB. But I am not able to get the 1 item that I defined. Instead, I got 11 items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find below a simple example on how to use the CosmosDB/SQL paged query:

```
    private static async Task Query()
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("https://{CosmosDB/SQL Account Name}.documents.azure.com:443/");
        DocumentClient documentClient = new DocumentClient(uri, "{CosmosDB/SQL Account Key}");

        int currentPageNumber = 1;
        int documentNumber = 1;

        IDocumentQuery<Book> query = documentClient.CreateDocumentQuery<Book>("dbs/{CosmoDB/SQL Database Name}/colls/{CosmoDB/SQL Collection Name}", new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 10 }).AsDocumentQuery();

        while (query.HasMoreResults)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"----- PAGE {currentPageNumber} -----");

            foreach (Book book in await query.ExecuteNextAsync())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"[{documentNumber}] {book.Id}");
                documentNumber++;
            }

            currentPageNumber++;
        }
    }
```

Per exception described in your question **Cross partition query is required but disabled**, update the feed options as follows:

```
var feedOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true};
```

Find a more comprehensive example at https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/blob/d17c0ca5be739a359d105cf4112443f65ca2cb72/samples/code-samples/Queries/Program.cs#L554-L576.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I followed the URL you provided but it's still not working for some reason. I have added to the last part of my question above. Thanks!

Comment: Please update the question with the exception you're seeing.

Comment: Change the feed options to var feedOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true};

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I am able to get response from CosmosDB but I am getting all the items, not 1 item that I specified.

Comment: It's because you're adding *all* results to the list before returning (e.g. while (query.HasMoreResults){}).

Comment: Cool, sure thing!

Answer (score 1):

you are not specifying any where criteria for your specific item...so you are getting all results..try specifying criteria for the item (id , name etc) you are looking for. And keep in mind cross partition queries consume much more RUs n time, you can revisit architecture of your data model..Ideally always do queries with in same partition

Comment: But I thought MaxItemCount is the one to define how many documents in one page.. Why do we need to specify more criteria?

Comment: There could be total 11 docs...and page size is 1(MaxItemCount) ...but query is executed 11 times as query.HasMoreResults is true till all records.but if you need some specific item, u need to add the criteria via linq Where

Comment: Just try it once removing query.HasMoreResults..it should then return only 1 doc, but that could be any random doc